# How can I display text below a selected dropdown option in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am writing a code wherein the image of the animal will be displayed & I have to select the name of the animal from the dropdown box.

The dropdown box will contain list of animals such as dog, cat, lion. Suppose, If I select dog and as soon as dog option is selected, following text should be displayed "A dog is a domestic mammal of the family Canidae and the order Carnivora."

Similarly, if I select cat option, following text should be displayed  "Cats have a strong flexible body, quick reflexes, sharp teeth"."

My code is as follows:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}
 
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
 
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Section 2'),
    );
  }
}
 
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
 
 
  final String title;
 
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}
 
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
 String _selectedAnimal="Dog";
 var animal={'Dog':'W1','Cat':'W2','Lion':'W3'};
 
 
 List _animals=[];
 AnimalDependentDropDown(){
   animal.forEach((key, value) {
     _animals.add(key);
   });
 }
 
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    AnimalDependentDropDown();
  }
  @override
 
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(
        margin:EdgeInsets.all(15),
 
        child: Column(
 
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(height: 23,),
          Align(
           alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
           child:Text("Animal",  style: TextStyle(fontWeight:FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 18),),
          ),
            Container(
              width: 400,
              child: DropdownButton(
                value: _selectedAnimal,
                onChanged: (newValue){
                  setState(() {
                     _selectedAnimal="$newValue";
                  });
                },
                
                items:_animals.map((animal){
                  return DropdownMenuItem(
                    child: Text(animal),
                    value:animal,
                  );
                }).toList(),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 23,),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

After selecting option from dropdown box, I am not able to display text.

Comment: Kindly share your code with question

Comment: I have edited my post by including code.

Comment: Where it will show `W1` based on selection?  inside DropDownButton or outside in column?

Comment: You want this output ? https://ibb.co/QH6R7K6

Answer (score 0):

While you are using Map key dropDownButton, you can use selected key to show the value.

```
  Text(" ${animal[_selectedAnimal]}"),
```

```dart
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String? _selectedAnimal;
  Map<String, String> animal = {
    'Dog': 'A dog is a domestic mammal of the family Canidae and the order Carnivora.',
    'Cat': 'Cats have a strong flexible body, quick reflexes, sharp teeth',
    'Lion': 'W3'
  };

  late final List _animals = animal.keys.toList();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            const SizedBox(height: 23),
            const Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Text(
                "Animal",
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 400,
              child: DropdownButton(
                value: _selectedAnimal,
                onChanged: (newValue) {
                  setState(() {
                    _selectedAnimal = "$newValue";
                  });
                },
                items: _animals.map((animal) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem(
                    child: Text(animal),
                    value: animal,
                  );
                }).toList(),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 24),
            Text(" ${animal[_selectedAnimal]}"),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Glad to help, you can find more about [Map](https://api.dart.dev/be/180791/dart-core/Map-class.html)

Comment: In the previous code, the description about animal is a single line but if the description is a paragraph then I want to categorize the description as brief description followed by detailed description.

Comment: You can play with `_selectedAnimal` by setting some logic. I may prefer creating model class.

Comment: Got the desired output. Thanks.

Comment: As soon as dog option is selected, following text is displayed "A dog is a domestic mammal of the family Canidae and the order Carnivora." Now after this text, I want to have user defined input regarding user description of animal. I have used textfield for the same but still I am not getting the desired output.

Comment: It would be nice to stay on specific issue, you can create separate question with a minimal, reproducible example